# get current user uid from in flash (swf) object published on facebook wall like you tube movies

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-actionscript-api

I have published my Mp3Player.swf on facebook wall using stream publish. i need to get the uid of the current user in side my player which is running just like you tube move on the facebook wall. i am using facebook action script sdk for this.

if i embed my player inside an html page and directly access that url on browser my player is able to connect to facebook but if the same player is published on facebook wall using stream publish nothing happens.

Can any one tell me is it possible or not if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't access or authenticate users through the swf published on the wall. You can however, ask them to fill in a form which would lead the user to the next step (canvas/tab app?). I think Facebook would be filtering any API calls that would come from a published swf. How would you see the login screen customized for a tab app? Also, just imagine on how a spammy app can spread if published swfs would have that level of access...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my client wants to update the no of times song has been played by a particular facebook user for which i required this feature. but i think i will not be able to deliver this.

Comment: can i get a non expiring access token for my app for a user which i can use like this in urlrequest "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20pic_square%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()&access_token=xxxx"

Comment: I doubt you can make any API call from your published SWF. Sometimes it's better to explain how things work to the client, develop a tab app (if they have a Facebook page) or canvas app to work together with the Flash file. Give overall stats for number of plays and offer option to register in swf and complete registration on tab app - then you can correlate the two and you get your results. I come from an agency background so I know what you're going through with such requests...